# scope.$digest() not updating local scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

In an angular app running on 1.3.0-beta.15, I have a directive that looks like this:

```
.directive('digester', function() {

  return {
    scope: {
      object: '=',
      digestTrigger: '='
    },

    templateUrl: 'some-template.html,

    link: function(scope) {
      scope.digestTrigger = function() {
        scope.$digest();
      }       
    }
  };
});
```

a template that looks like this:

```
<div>{{object.title}}</div>
```

a service somewhere that looks like this:

```
.service('serviceToCallDigest', function() {

  return {
    object: {
      title: 'someTitle'
    },

    digestTrigger: function() {},

    someFunction: function() {
      this.object.title = 'newTitle'; 
      this.digestTrigger();
    }
  };
});
```

and a controller that gets the service injected like this:

```
.controller('someCtrl', function($scope, serviceToCallDigest) {
  $scope.serviceToCallDigest = serviceToCallDigest;
}
```

and wires up the directive like this:

```
<digester 
  digest-trigger="serviceToCallDigest.digestTrigger" 
  object="serviceToCallDigest.object">
</digester>
```

Whats happening here is, as the directive gets the `digestTrigger` injected (as an empty function) it sets the function to fire the directives local `$digest()` function, and by that enabeling code from outside the directive to trigger the local digest whenever appropriate.

I know that `$apply()` is adviced to use, which fires `$digest()` at the `$rootscope` level, but I'm in a perfomance critical situation, where I need to update directives locally.

This setup has worked fine until upgrading to 1.3.0-beta.16 or newer versions. Now the new `object.title` is not passed to the directive and updated in the view, when `someFunction` is called.

Does anyone know why this is the case and what to do to work around it?

Comment: _`a controller that gets the service injected, and wires up the directive like this`_ how? can you show your controller

Comment: Hey, sorry for being a little unclear on that part, I have now added the controller code, hope that makes sense.

Comment: Ok, now here is a plunkr can you tell me what is not working? http://plnkr.co/edit/GKtYbC?p=preview You would need to provide `restrict` for your directive right? ANother question, why do you manually need to do digest?

Comment: Thanks a lot for writing that plunkr, it clearly works there, which I am really confused about, guess it is something else in my application, that beta.16+ versions affect. You are right, I need a `restrict` as well. The reason for needing manually digests, is because I have a LOT of bindings, and loops running every 16ms, where different parts of the app needs updating, so to not have everything update 60 times a second, the different directives only digest themselves whenever appropriate. Again, thank you very much for helping, I will continue my search for the error in my app.

Comment: Sure. See if you can replicate the issue in plnkr and post here.. Best of luck!

Comment: Hi again, ok now I have been able to replicate the issue here: http://plnkr.co/edit/OzdfxoQfDfwsmqi8G5Hi?p=preview . It seems that if the binding is a primitive integer instead of an object, it doesnt update, when the `setTimeout` is called (I use `setTimeout` and not `$timeout` in order to NOT trigger `$rootscope.$digest()` ). The update is happening in the plunkr right now, but not if you change the angular version to beta.16 or greater.